# ngx-toastr is not working on webapi with angular on visual studio 2017

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I created a project webapi with angular. Everything is working fine except when I try to `import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';` in my app.module.ts. I have installed it in the "ClientApp" folder:

[image]

like so: `npm install ngx-toastr --save` and `npm install @angular/animations --save` but it doesn't work this is the only thing I get even in my devtools

> Cannot GET /

**Implementation**

```
upload(id) {
    if (id == null)
            return;

      let selectedFile = this.uploader.queue.find(s => s.id == id);
      if (selectedFile) {
        console.log(selectedFile.id);
        const formData = new FormData();
        //formData.append(selectedFile.file.name, selectedFile.file);
        formData.append(selectedFile.id, selectedFile.file);
        const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `api/upload`, formData, {
          reportProgress: true,
        });

        this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            selectedFile.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
          }
          else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            selectedFile.message = event.body.toString();
            this.toastr.success('Successfully uploaded file', 'Notification');
            //this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('myModal').open()
            this.service.getUploads();
          }
        });
      }
  }
```

Where should I install the ngx-toasr? What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Can you able to make stackblitz link

Comment: If the web api and the frontend are in two separate files, I do not have this issue.

Comment: Please add your code for better understanding